# minTime from selection in user input jquery

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am trying to get the minTime to be set by the first selection(FromTime).  When the user selects the option of (ToTime) the minTime will be preset by what the user already selected in the FromTime.

```
    $('#FromTime').timepicker()

$('#ToTime').timepicker({
    'minTime': $('#FromTime').on('change', function() ??? ,
    'maxTime': '11:30pm',
    'showDuration': true
});
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `changeTime` event on `#FromTime`

```
$( "#FromTime" ).timepicker();
$('#ToTime').timepicker({
   'maxTime': '11:30pm',
   'showDuration': true
});
$('#FromTime').on('changeTime', function() {
    $('#ToTime').timepicker('option', {'minTime': $(this).val()});
});
```